# Update Caption of Page from Page itself

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I need to update the Page Caption on a Tab Control in Access. I tried the following code:

```
Private Sub tabName_AfterUpdate()
  MyTabControl.Pages(Me.MyTabControl.Value).Caption = Me.tabName
End Sub
```

This works well to set the Caption, but after using Tab or Enter in the field and execution of the above code I end up on the next record. What can I do to stay on the same page?

```
Private Sub tabName_AfterUpdate()
  MyTabControl.Pages(Me.MyTabControl.Value).Caption = Me.tabName
  Forms!frmMailing.Controls!MyTabControl = Me.MyTabControl.Value
End Sub
```

leads to the next record as well, while

```
Private Sub tabName_AfterUpdate()
  MyTabControl.Pages(Me.MyTabControl.Value).Caption = Me.tabName
  Forms!frmMailing.Controls!MyTabControl = Me.MyTabControl.Value-1
End Sub
```

Will jump to the previous page of the same record (as expected)!

Comment: After some more testing I found this workaround (without being the proper solution):

    Private Sub tabName_AfterUpdate()
      MyTabControl.Pages(Me.MyTabControl.Value).Caption = Me.tabName
      Forms!frmMailing.Controls!MyTabControl = Me.MyTabControl.Value-1
      Forms!frmMailing.Controls!MyTabControl = Me.MyTabControl.Value+1
    End Sub

Be aware: This will not work on Page(0)! For my problem however the Tabs to be renamed have always an index greater than 1, so this will work always.

Answer (score -1):

please try following code example:

```
Forms("dataimport").Command8.Caption = "test"
DoEvents
```

command8 = control at the form "dataimport"
also the form should be opened